# What is a shroud (in aviation terms or engineering terms)?

Tags: aircraft-design

Please can someone explain what a shroud is and give examples of types of shrouds and their uses on aircraft?

Comment: This reads like you're asking us to answer a homework question.

Comment: To get a good answer you will need to add a lot more context. The place I've heard the term the most is in the HPT of jet engines, where they are segmented pieces that form the outside wall of the flowpath.

Answer (score 4):

It's "shrouded" in secrecy.  A shroud is something that hides from view.  An access panel hides things from view, but it's main function is as a removable section of an enclosed structure.  A shroud's only job is to block light, heat, fluids, or gases from going from A to B, or to manage where they go.  A shroud on the outside of an airplane who's only function is to manage the airflow for drag reduction is a fairing.

In engineering terms, a shroud is usually a non-structural protective panel, that isn't a fairing or access panel, that "hides" something either from view, from a heat source, some sort of internal flow disturbance, or some potential contaminating substance.

So if I have a an electric actuator I need to protect from the heat of an adjacent bleed air duct, I'll put a panel, a heat shroud, around the actuator or the duct to create a separation between them.  If I have a problem with water migrating through the floor and dripping onto black boxes (which happens a lot in airliners), I may put a shroud over the boxes, basically an umbrella, as a kind of band-aid solution to redirect the water.  I may put a shroud panel over a mass of wiring and plumbing on an engine to protect it from heat, fluids, water, to smooth internal airflow, or just for looks.

Probably the most common use of shrouds on airplanes is as heat shields.  Shrouded ducts, exhaust shrouds, etc.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the original meaning is a burial cloth.

Comment: Also, exhaust shrouds for carb heat and cabin heat in light planes.